# Can OCaml check tail recursion

Tags: ocaml

Is there a way to get ocaml to tell me if a function implements a recursion using tail recursion? I don't mean reading the code. I mean getting ocaml to tell me, say like this:

```
let x = tail_recursion f;;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can compile your source code with '-annot'. It will produce an annotation file, that some editors can use.

In caml-mode (emacs) the command ist:

```
 M-x caml-types-show-call
```

Comment: I did ocaml -annot a.ml. But I don't see an annotation file. I have a.cmi, a.cmo, a.o.

Comment: Also, instead of emacs/xemacs, is there a command line tool that I can use?

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped. I did do "ocamlc -annot a.ml. I don't have any "annotation file". I'm using 4.00.1.

Comment: `ocamlc -annot foo.ml` should produce `foo.annot`, unless there are type errors. (If `foo.ml` depends on other modules you'll have to pass them as usual, too.)

Comment: No. I don't have a.annot. I'm sure my a.ml file is ok. It's just: let rec ffffffffff x = 
  if x == 0 then 
    0 
  else 
    ffffffffff (x - 1);;

Comment: Nevermind. My mistake. I types "ocamlc a.ml -annot" instead of "ocamlc -annot a.ml". Thanks everyone.

Comment: According to the earlier reply, I should be able to tell from the annotation file on whether a recursive function uses tail or not. I'm reading the annotation and I don't see any direct information on that. Is there a tool to interpret the annotation file?

Comment: You should get an entry that looks something like `"test.ml" 1 0 19 "test.ml" 1 0 22\ncall(\n  tail\n)`. Note that this refers to the textual extent of a *call site* (not a function definition) within the source file. I'm not sure if there are any editor-independent tools to parse this information, as I just use emacs.